# Netplan bridge issue

Tags: networking, bridge, netplan

I am trying to create a bridge using Netplan.
I copied this part of [the guide](https://netplan.io/examples#bridging).

But it gives me an error:

```
root@ubuntu:~# netplan generate
Error in network definition //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 9 column 10: br0: interface eth0 is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, it worked well for a new vps.

```
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
  ens3:
    dhcp4: no
bridges:
  br0:
    addresses: [ 10.1.3.43/24 ]
    interfaces: [ ens3 ]
    gateway4: 10.1.3.1
    macaddress: 00:16:3e:7f:ae:93
    nameservers:
       addresses:  [ 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your ethernet card has different name than eth0

Check your system with

```
lshw -class network
```

You can look into the logical name and replace it in your netcfg.yaml